# EF 6 Raw SQL Queries null value

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I try to fetch data from my db and bind it to my internal class object but all field is null it should have some data.

here my internal class

```
    internal class Query1
    {
        public decimal? workedhours {get;set;}
        public decimal? woff { get; set; }
        public decimal? abilact { get; set; }
        public decimal? abilori { get; set; }
        public decimal? rratio { get; set; }
        public decimal? frec { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is my query

```
 var ttk = new SqlParameter("@ttk", element.tkinit);
 var year = new SqlParameter("@year",start.Substring(1,3));
 var ed = new SqlParameter("@end",end);
 var st = new SqlParameter("@start",start);

    string sqlQuery = @"SELECT 
    SUM(inq.thhrwkdw) workedhours,
    SUM(inq.thcrdc) woff,
    SUM(inq.thdobidb) abilact,
    SUM(inq.thdowkdb) abilori,
    ((SUM(inq.thdobidb)-SUM(inq.thdowkdb))/(SUM(inq.thdowkdb)+1) * 100) + 100 rratio,
    SUM(inq.thdocodc) frec
    FROM dbo.inqtimewahs inq
    INNER JOIN dbo.timekeep tk ON tk.tkinit = inq.ivalue
    WHERE inq.ivalue = '@ttk'AND inq.iper IN 
(SELECT iper FROM inqtimewahs WHERE iper LIKE '%@year' AND iper >= '@start' AND iper <= '@end') AND tk.tktmdate IS NULL";
    resultQ1 = eContext.Database.SqlQuery<Query1>(sqlQuery, ttk, year, st, ed).SingleOrDefault();
```

Did I miss something because I have another query but more simple than this one and it fetch data from other table. 
It is the same query using in another application but without all the binding and parameter but it work in that old app.

Comment: Did you do a test run of your query directly against your db? Did you make sure you used the exact same query, with the same input values?

Comment: How about using eContext.Database.Log to see exact query and see if it's really what it should be?

Comment: I will try that  when I got home right now in train

Comment: thank Evk with database.log manage to see what the problem didn't know that feature my star variable and end variable was mess up

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to put quotes around parameters:

```
SELECT iper FROM inqtimewahs WHERE iper LIKE '%' + @year AND iper >= @start AND iper <= @end
```